# a<-7<b:b assignment with succint conditional in R?

Tags: r

This expression:

```
a<-7<b:b
```

means to assign 7 to `a` if `7<b==TRUE` otherwise `b`. How can this be done in R?

**Building on the Paul Hiemstra, how to make it more succint? Dummy var or?**

```
M<-matrix(rep(0,30),
  ncol=3,
  dimnames=list(NULL,c('q1','a1','s1')))
dummy1<-round(rexp(n=1,rate=server1))
M[loopVar,'s1']<-ifelse(M[loopVar,'q1']<dummy1,M[loopVar,'q1'],dummy1)
```

Comment: You use a variable called c, this is however a builtin primitive. It is advisable not to do this.

Comment: What language is your original expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
b = runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)
a = ifelse(7 < b, 7, b)
```

and it is even vectorized.

Comment: Could you add an example of object M (matrix?) to your question. This would make it much easier to help you with the syntax.

Comment: Your solution above looks fine to me. If you provide more details on how you plan to loop through the matrix, we could help you even more.

Comment: I like small and short questions, it helps people to concentrate. Thank you for your help. (I use for -loop but trying to find more succint way of doing, I have a good feeling where to look at with  `lapply` etc but I do not want to jam all of this stuff to one question.) +1

Comment: Thanks! If you have an additional question, just post a new one.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `ifelse` correct function for this paradigm, but for this application you can just use `pmin` which should be a bit quicker:

```
a <- pmin(7,b)
```