# Is there a similar way like x ? y : z in R?

Tags: r

With

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1:5), v2=c(9,32,6,17,11))
```

I need to add a new column v3 with value 1 or 0 based on whether values in v2 are larger than 10 or not so that:

```
df
  v1 v2 v3
1  1  9  0
2  2 32  1
3  3  6  0
4  4 17  1
5  5 11  1
```

Is there such thing like x ? y : z in R? If not, what's a good way to solve the above? Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409817/a-7bb-assignment-with-succint-conditional-in-r/9409906

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ifelse(..)` comes closest:

```
R> df <- data.frame(v1=c(1:5), v2=c(9,32,6,17,11))
R> df$v3 <- ifelse(df$v2 > 10, 1, 0)
R> df
  v1 v2 v3
1  1  9  0
2  2 32  1
3  3  6  0
4  4 17  1
5  5 11  1
R>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether ifelse is faster, but this is easier to read:

```
> d <- data.frame(v1=c(1:5), v2=c(9,32,6,17,11))
> d$v3 <- as.numeric(d$v2 > 10)
> d
  v1 v2 v3
1  1  9  0
2  2 32  1
3  3  6  0
4  4 17  1
5  5 11  1
```

Comment: eye of the beholder ... I often prefer explicit `ifelse` constructions to logical -> numeric coercion ...